# Get equals values from two nested objects

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have two objects like these ones:

```js
const obj1 = {
  ch1: {
    as: ['a', 'b'],
    ns: ['1']
  }
  ch2: {
    ss: ['#', '*', '+'],
    ts: ['2', '3']
  }
}

const obj2 = {
  ch1: {
    as: ['a', 'g'],
  }
  ch2: {
    ss: ['#', '-', '+'],
    ts: ['1', '5']
  }
}

const result = findSimilarities(obj1, obj2)
```

should returns:

```js
[
  'a' // because obj1.ch1.as and obj2.ch1.as contain 'a'
  '#' // because obj1.ch2.ss and obj2.ch2.ss contain '#'
  '+' // because obj1.ch2.ss and obj2.ch2.ss contain '+'
]
```

I can define Level 1 as `ch1` or `ch2`, Level 2 as `as`, `ns`, `ss` or `ts` and Level 3 the strings inside the arrays.

So what I'm interested in are che value at level 3 that the two objects have in common.

Honestly I didn't know how to start..

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your result? That will be our starting point as we try to help you.

Comment: @TusharShahi You are right. I didn't know how to start. I don't know ho two compare two nested objects

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  What is `che level 3`?  Is it part of your example?  If not, please add it.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the syntax of your nested objects is incorrect

Comment: @MattMorgan Thank you for noted it! I edit my main message

Comment: @BeerusDev Thank you for your reply. No, it is correct. My data structure is like in the example

Comment: Why don't you just start from start of object and traversal to wanted values? You have to start somewhere... You need to try something

Comment: You will have to start with thinking if the object structure is going to be the same for obj1,obj2. If yes then think of a way to get the **keys of an object**, you have the keys you have the associated value. You get **your nested keys** you can then get **intersection of arrays.**

Comment: Whatever I have mentioned in bold is something you can use as keywords to google. You will get SO answer links for most of them. You combine them, you get your answer. For sure, you will learn a lot of extra stuff, which you will **probably** not learn when you get one fixed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also want to leave my solution here. It will work properly on the data structures like you described above. On whatever object depth and if arrays will contains only primitive values.

```
function findSimilarities(obj1, obj2) {
    if (obj1 instanceof Array && obj2 instanceof Array) {
        return findSimilarArrayValues(obj1, obj2)
    }

    if (!obj1 instanceof Object || !obj1 instanceof Object) {
        return [];
    }

    const similarKeys = findSimilarObjectKeys(obj1, obj2);
    return similarKeys.map(key => findSimilarities(obj1[key], obj2[key])).flat()
}

function findSimilarObjectKeys(obj1, obj2) {
    return Object.keys(obj1).filter(key => obj2.hasOwnProperty(key));
}

function findSimilarArrayValues(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.filter(item => arr2.includes(item));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is start with a function, `function getMatches(obj1, obj2) { ...`.

Iterate over the first-level keys of `obj1` with `Object.keys(obj1).foreach( key2 => ...`. (2 to represent what you call level 2)

Then, iterate over THOSE keys, `Object.keys(obj1[key2]).foreach(key3 > ...`

So now you have an array that you can access via `obj1[key2][key3]`, and you can access the array to compare against via `obj2[key2][key3]`. So now you just have to iterate every value in `obj1[key2][key3]` and check if it's in `obj2[key2][key3]`. If a key is in both, smash it in an array, and then return the array at the end of the function

[edit] you may have to use some sort of check, or the optional chaining operator `?.`, to access the keys on `obj2`, in case there's a key on obj1 that isn't on obj2

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would recommend:

Create a function lets call it `function compare(obj1, obj2)`, then create two `Object.values` variables followed by an empty array `var equivalent = [];`

After that have a `forEach` function that searches both objects, and the final product should look something like:

```
function compare(obj1, obj2) {
  var values1 = Object.values(obj1);
  var values2 = Object.values(obj2);
  var equivalent = [];

  var keys = Object.keys(obj1);
  keys.forEach(k => {
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(k) && obj2.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      if (obj1[k] === obj2[k]) {
        equivalent.push(obj1[k]);
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(equivalent);
}

compare(obj1, obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to start with [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

- Use `Object.keys` to find all keys in first object, `Object.protoype.hasOwnProperty()` to check if these keys exist in object 2
- Repeat that for levels 1 and 2
- Extract the values common to level 3 arrays using `Array.prototype.filter()` on the array from first object to keep only items found in its match from second object:

```js
function findSimilarities(x, y) {
  const res = [];
  for (const k1 of Object.keys(x)) { //Level 1
    if (y.hasOwnProperty(k1)) {
      const xo1 = x[k1];
      const yo1 = y[k1];
      for (const k2 of Object.keys(xo1)) { //Level 2
        if (yo1.hasOwnProperty(k2)) {
          const xo2 = xo1[k2];
          const yo2 = yo1[k2];
          if (Array.isArray(xo2) && Array.isArray(yo2)) { //Level 3 are arrays
            const dupXo2 = xo2.filter(el => yo2.includes(el));
            res.push(...dupXo2);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}

const obj1 = {
  ch1: {
    as: ['a', 'b'],
    ns: ['1']
  },
  ch2: {
    ss: ['#', '*', '+'],
    ts: ['2', '3']
  }
};

const obj2 = {
  ch1: {
    as: ['a', 'g'],
  },
  ch2: {
    ss: ['#', '-', '+'],
    ts: ['1', '5']
  }
};

const result = findSimilarities(obj1, obj2);
console.log(result);
```